# prime ng datable paginator resets to first page on data change

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the primeng datable component like this

```
<p-dataTable [value]="myModel" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="5" > <p-dataTable>
```

Givent I am on a page other than 1 with sorting enable, if I modifiy `myModel` table, it resets my paginator to page 1...
Has anyone been able to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and actually, it's pretty dumb, I was devastated by my own stupidity when I found this.

Question : is your datatable in a `*ngIf="myModel"` ?

Comment: Because everytime your ngIf becomes false, it destroys the primeNG component, meaning it is resetting the pager. Try it, delete the ngIf, and see how it works so good

Comment: my Model is not reset. But when it mutates it resets the pager if sorting is enabled on some column

Comment: Then please post all the code related to the sorting, the datatable and pagination, it would be easier to help.